# How many string of three decimal digits...?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

How many string of three decimal digits have exactly two digits that $4$s ? 
I know the answer will be $27$, but I don't know why... ?

Comment: May I naively ask why the downvotes? Bad formulation of the problem?

Answer (score 3):

You want a string of digits of the form $\rm 44X$, $\rm4X4$, or $\rm X44$, where $\rm X$ is not $4$. Then, there are $9$ digits $\rm X$ could be: $0,1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9$. We have $3$ types of string, and $9$ strings of each type, so the total number of strings is $3*9=27$.

If we were talking about numbers instead of strings, you could say $044$ does not qualify as a $3$-digit number, giving a total of $26$.

Comment: that is easy now for me ! Thank you.